# Llamar clase Magnetic Sensor en activity main Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Buena tarde expertos

Tengo el siguiente código de una clase de tipo `Main` que usa el `sensor Magnético` de `Android` y muestra los valores en `textView`:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SensorMagnetic extends Activity  implements SensorEventListener {

private TextView magneticX;
private TextView magneticY;
private TextView magneticZ;
private SensorManager sensorManager = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    magneticX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valMag_X);
    magneticY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valMag_Y);
    magneticZ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valMag_Z);

    sensorManager.registerListener(this,
            sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {

    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    sensorManager.registerListener(this,
            sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    synchronized (this) {
        if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
            magneticX.setText( Float.toString( sensorEvent.values[0]));
            magneticY.setText( Float.toString( sensorEvent.values[1]));
            magneticZ.setText( Float.toString( sensorEvent.values[2]));
        }
    }

   }
}
```

pero yo necesito "llamarla" por así decirlo desde una Activity de tipo Main que tiene métodos implementados y que por consiguiente no puedo poner otro, ejemplo:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
/*. etc etc... (esta clase tiene un método onCreate y es de tipo Launcher)
```

Cómo puedo hacer para usar mi clase `SensorMagnetic` en mi Clase `MainActivity`
gracias de antemano espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: No puedes reusar SensorMagnetic  en MainActivity, MainActivity debe tener la misma implementación de SensorMagnetic  para que use el sensor magnetico, he agregado una respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que lo que deseas es usar tu clase `SensorMagnetic` en `MainActivity`, recuerda que `SensorMagnetic` es en realidad una `Activity` y no hay forma de utilizarla en `MainActivity` .

Lo que debes realizar es que tu clase MainActivity debe implementar [SensorEventListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEventListener.html):

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements SensorEventListener {
...
...
```

Cuando realices esto debes implementar los métodos:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {

}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

}
```

y agregar las referencias de SensorManager que se encuentran en tu clase `SensorMagnetic`, en resumen debes agregar el código que realizas en tu clase `SensorMagnetic`.

Comment: Hola y gracias por tu respuesta, efectivamente es lo que quiero, el detalle es que  ya tengo un "implements SurfaceHolder.Callback" es por eso que me gustaría saber si hay alguna otra forma de usar mi clase en mi MainActivity, de antemano gracias nuevamente